# Get value from field in Firebase Firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a String value from a field call Number, a phone number to be exact, in a Firebase Firestore database.

However, I do not know how to do it.

```
private fun lookIntoDatabaseForClient() {
    setMobileNumberToEditText()

    bbdd.collection("Taxi").whereEqualTo("number", number).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if(task.isSuccessful && !task.result.isEmpty) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Client exist in database. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Cliente does not exist in database.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting on logcat?

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection on how to read multiple documents? This shows how to get to the individual documents in your `task.result`. The `data` there is a `Map` from which you can get the individual field values.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, what is the value of `number` inside `.whereEqualTo("number", number)`? Please respond using @AlexMamo